# Express not serving files correctly on heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, server

I am trying to try out webrtc so I fired up a peer server on my localhost(PC) which worked fine, but on putting it on Heroku I ap getting this error(whereas it ran perfectly fine on my local machine)

`` Starting process with command `node peer-server.js`
2017-04-21T19:13:50.530426+00:00 app[web.1]: Peer server up and running on port 39711
2017-04-21T19:13:51.755765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-04-21T19:13:52.912277+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=peerconnecto.herokuapp.com request_id=9379c3a3-b2f7-47b1-972e-8800bd9afb4e fwd="197.210.44.53" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2017-04-21T19:13:52.898975+00:00 app[web.1]: attempted to server peer messenger static files via /app/public/index.html
2017-04-21T19:13:52.910539+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/index.html'
2017-04-21T19:13:52.910541+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native) ``

Below is my server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    const index = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html');
    res.sendFile(index);
    console.log(`attempted to server peer messenger static files via ${index}`);
});

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Peer server up and running on port ${app.get('port')}`);
});

var options = {
    debug: true
}

app.use('/peerjs', ExpressPeerServer(server, options));
```

I have a public folder that contains my static files and on the [page](https://peerconnecto.herokuapp.com) all that I see is *Not Found*

Please I need help

Comment: Maybe you forgot to commit and push public directory. Or your app is not running in `/app` directory.

Comment: What is your app directory structure? IT's looking for index.html in the /app/public directory. Is that where the file resides? Or is /public in the root?

Comment: yes I have an index.html in the /app/public directory